# Как рисовать на загруженной картинке?

Tags: delphi, изображения

```
begin
 if OpenDlg.Execute then Img.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenDlg.FileName);
end;
```

Как после этого рисовать на загруженной картинке? `TImage` загружать в `tbitmap/tjpegimage`?

Comment: TImage  не предназначен для рисования. То, что можно рисовать, если загружен bmp, - это недоработка. Рисовать нужно, к примеру, на TPictureBox или прямо на форме. А загруженную в Tjpegimage картинку там [нарисовать просто](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/open_jpeg_file.html).

Если нужно рисовать поверх картинки, то вначале рисуем картинку, потом рисуем нужное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рисовать можно, например, с помощью TPaintBox (вкладка System).
Например, нужно нарисовать в PaintBox1 изображение Image1 и линию, идущую из левого верхнего угла (так как каретка изначально будет там) в точку с координатами (100;100).
Необходимо обрабатывать событие OnPaint объекта PaintBox1:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
     //рисуем картинку Image1
     PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,Image1.Picture.Graphic);
     //рисуем линию, после этого каретка будет находиться
     //в точке с координатами (100, 100)
     Paintbox1.Canvas.LineTo(100,100);
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо!
у меня отображение идет так:
    image1.Proportional:=true;
но DRAW загружает оригинальный Graphic, размеры которого не могу поменять.  
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,Image1.Picture.Graphic);

Comment: Для этого можно использовать 

PaintBox1.Canvas.StretchDraw(TRect, TGraphics);

Например:

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);

var
//прямоугольник
rect:TRect;

begin
//задаем параметры прямоугольника (квадрат со стороной 100)
rect.Left := 0;
rect.Top   := 0;
rect.Right := 100;
rect.Bottom  := 100;
//рисуем в заданном прямоугольнике rect
PaintBox1.Canvas.StretchDraw(rect, image1.Picture.Graphic);
end;

Comment: вот это прям помогло больше,чем я за весь день нашёл! спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Можно попробовать следующим образом:

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);

var

rect:TRect;

bmp:tbitmap;

begin

rect.Left := 0;

rect.Top   := 0;

rect.Right := 100;

rect.Bottom  := 100;

bmp := TBitmap.Create();

bmp.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);

try

  PaintBox1.Canvas.CopyRect(rect, bmp.Canvas, rect);

finally

  bmp.free;

end;


end;

Comment: Canvas.CopyRect(dest, canvas, src) - копирует из canvas прямоугольник src и рисует скопированное в прямоугольнике dest объекта, метод которого был вызван